# How to get multiple button.Text value depending on which button is clicked

Tags: c#, datagridview

so in my program I want to click a button and put that button.Text value into say a datagridview table. I have 16 buttons, and so I don't want to repeat the whole code for each and every button but call a singular method which would get the button.Text such that

```
//this would get button4.Text value and input into the table.

private void button4_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
items_Add();
}

//this would get button5.Text value and input into table.

private void button5_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
items_Add();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use button's text while making decision what to be done in your common method for all the buttons
and ofcourse you can make common event listener by subscribing all the buttons to single event listener.

like

```
button1.Click += button_Click;
button2.Click += button_Click;
button3.Click += button_Click;
...

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = sender as Button;
    if(b == null)
        return; // you can return, or throw an exception. It depends on your requirements.
    string text = b.Text;

    items_Add(text); //assuming this is your common method
}
```

EDIT: added some validation on the `sender` to make sure it's really a `Button`

Comment: I think it's best to always verify if the sender is really of the expected type, that's why I edited the answer.

Comment: @LucMorin indeed, your edit is required. Thanks for Edit

Answer (score 1):

This might do the trick for you. Just subscribe to the event on all button.

```
button1.Click += myEventHandler;
button2.Click += myEventHandler;
button3.Click += myEventHandler;
button4.Click += myEventHandler;
button5.Click += myEventHandler;
button6.Click += myEventHandler;
```

and then

```
private void myEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    items_Add();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is another method that is more flexible for every button click.

Bind all the button click event to `button1_Click`.

```
Button btn = sender as Button;
switch (btn.Text)
{
    case "textval1":
       items_Add();
        break;

    case "textval2":
        items_Add();
        break;

    case "textval3":
       items_Add();
       break;
}
```